# Multiple MSMQ communication in WCF

Tags: wcf, msmq

I am using a client server application in which client send request to server in request queue, server receive this request object from queue process it and send response in response queue which is received by client application. I want same functionality in wcf service and client so whether I need to create two different end points for both msmq and if yes than how same client will work with both endpoints.

Comment: I am voting up once, because I think it is bad manners to vote down and not leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not think of it as strictly a client server application.
You do have a request originator referred to as client and a request processor referred to as Server,
but when thinking WCF- client is the one sending the message, server is the one receiving. Meaning that in WCf terms, at first your client is really a classic "client" and the server is really  a classic "server". But when you get to the point after the original request is processed and needs to be sent back- the roles are reversed! the server becomes a WCf client and the client becomes a WCf server.

What this means is that you processes need to expose a separate endpoint for each other. The server listens on a certain EP for incoming messages (requests), and the client listens on a certain EP for incoming messages (responses).

Hope this clarifies things a bit.